# Backbone.js event trigger

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, eventtrigger

How to bind a change event to model from view to change name and display the changed name in view block.

```
Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.on("change:name", function(model){
            var name = model.get("name");
            alert("Changed my name to " + name );
        });
    }
});

var pe = new Student({ name: "sinduja", age: 20});
pe.set({name: 'shalini'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't backbone trigger change events automatically on [model.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set)?

You just have to register your view to the change event.

```
Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //initialize variables
    }
});

StudentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(model) {
        _.bindAll(this);
        model.on("change:name",this.nameChanged)
    },
    nameChanged: function(evt) {
        console.log("name changed", evt)
    }

})
```

Usage:

```
var pe = new Student({ name: "sinduja", age: 20});
var sv = new StudentView(pe);
pe.set({name: 'shalini'});
```

Comment: Thanks...but i get only name changed as my output and not the changed name..wat shd i do to get the changed name?

Comment: Thanks a lot...i made changes now am able to get the changed name.

Comment: i have one doubt but wat do u in nameChanged() is tat u r printing jus the line "name changed" and one more thing is like wat variables can i initialize ther since am already passing it in d usage area

Answer (score 0):

I used to write my own custom stuff for reacting to bi-directional model/view changes, which is a bit of a maintenance pain. Then I found the plugin [Backbone.ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder).

It makes what you want to achieve stupidly easy. There are some good examples on the github readme page I linked you to so there's no point me giving any! If it seems a bit confusing at first I would say try your best to get it working as in the long run this plugin will save you countless hours, like it has for me.